# Incorrect attribute value type. Inappropriate value for sttributes "subnets: set of string required."

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc

I've passed subnet ids many times and haven't encountered this error before, I'm really not sure why or how to fix it.

I have my subnet resource block right here in my VPC module:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "subnet_1" {
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc_1.id
  cidr_block        = "10.0.0.0/24"
  availability_zone = var.region_az

  tags = {
    Name = "pcp-subnet-1"
  }
}
```

This is what the outputs file looks like for my subnet output:

```
output "subnet_1" {
  value = aws_subnet.subnet_1.id
}
```

This is my root module calling the subnet id output

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "./ecs"

  service_subnets  = module.vpc.subnet_1
  pcp_service_sg = module.vpc.pcp_service_sg
}
```

In my ecs module I have the variable listed here in my variables file

```
variable "service_subnets" {
  type = string
}
```

This is my ecs resource where the error is occurring

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "ecs-service" {
  name            = "python-cloud-project"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.pcp-ecs-task-definition.arn
  launch_type     = "FARGATE"
  network_configuration {
    subnets         = var.service_subnets
    security_groups = var.pcp_service_sg
    assign_public_ip = true
  }
  desired_count = 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`network_configuration` requires a list of subnets, you are passing only one subnet. What you can do is to create a list with one element:

```
module "ecs" {
  source = "./ecs"

  service_subnets  = [module.vpc.subnet_1]
  pcp_service_sg = module.vpc.pcp_service_sg
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did that and changed my variable type = (list(string)) and that did the trick

Comment: Although Terraform can automatically convert from `list(string)` to `set(string)` by discarding any duplicates, since we can see in the error message that the `subnets` argument expects a set anyway it may be clearer to declare your variable with `type = set(string)`, so that the users of the module can see that the ordering of the elements is unimportant.